# How to add default selected element in Symfony forms?

Tags: symfony

I want to add a default selected option in the select tag
Here's the code:

```
->add('datefinProjet', 'date', array(
'label'=>'Date fin Projet :', 
'years' => range(date('Y') - 20, date('Y') - 100),
'empty_value' => array('years'=>'' , 'month' => '', 'day' =>'' )))
```

I want the select list to start with the empty value `''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a error in your `empty_value` parameter. Should be 'year', not 'years'

```
    $builder->add('datefinProjet', 'date', array(
        'label'=>'Date fin Projet :',
        'years' => range(date('Y') - 20, date('Y') - 100),
        'empty_value' => array('year' => '', 'month' => '', 'day' => '')
    ));
```

Source: [Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/reference/forms/types/date.html#empty-value)